# My rear wheel is bent. How do I know which replacement rim would work?

Tags: rims, rear-wheel, diamondback

I have a 2015 Diamondback Insight 1. (http://dbcorp.diamondback.com/insight-1) The rear wheel is bent and I think needs replacement. The bike specs say that it's a "32h Equation R23 Doublewall" but I haven't been able to find a replacement. Which do you think would work for my bike?

Thanks so much!

Comment: How bent is bent?  It might be a minor bend that can be straightened (trued) by a bike shop or by you with a spoke tool.   This would likely be much cheaper than a new wheel, so its worth exploring.  Of course if your wheel is folded up then that might be too much.

Comment: When I bust a rim I replaced the whole wheel. It's likely to work out better for you to do the same. Given that I needed to be sure of having the bike I wasn't going to risk building the wheel myself, and buying a wheel is cheaper than buying a rim and having the wheel rebuilt (even if you reuse the spokes).

Answer (score 2):

That link appears to be a dealer-only one, I get a login prompt. It's a flat bar road bike and based on a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=2015%20Diamondback%20Insight%201%20wheel%20size) comes with 700c/ISO622 wheels and a 7 speed cassette (7 gears on the right hand shifter). The R23 in the name very probably means the original rim is 23mm wide.

[image]

That means any 7 speed narrow rim 700c wheel should work.

Comment: You might want to check the hub spacing - bikes like this use an odd mixture of road and mountain components (or at least mine does) and [apparently](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html) there are several standards for 7 speed hub spacings taking this into account.